# How can I relate to separate values ​as if they were one and that it will be reflected in my aggregated function of sum in postgesql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sum, aggregate-functions

I wrote a query that goes something like that:

```
select T1.col_1 , sum (col_2)

from table_1 T1
     join table_2 T2 on T1.col_match = T2.col_match 
     
   where T1 IN('value1','value2','value3')

  group by T1.col_1
```

and the result looks approximatly like this:

```
+---------+----------+
| values |   sum     |
+---------+----------+
| value1  | 547.748  |
| value2  | 161.235  |
| value3  | 591.245  |
+---------+----------+
```

and what I want is for two values - `value1 and value2` to be calculated togehther at the sum function (basically doing `547.748 + 161.235`)

do you know which operator\ function I can use in order to do so?

I'm quite new to SQL and English is not my native language so sorry if it came out a bit messy.

could realy use your help ! thanks to those who anwer (:

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below - using `case when expression`

```
select case when T1.col_1 in ('value1','value2') then 'Value' else T1.col_1 end as T1.col_1, 
       sum (col_2)
from table_1 T1 
       join table_2 T2 on T1.col_match = T2.col_match 
where T1 IN('value1','value2','value3')
group by case when T1.col_1 in ('value1','value2') then 'Value' else T1.col_1 end
```

Comment: A column alias can't be qualified. And it should be a column IN.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use a join:

```
select T1.groupby, sum(col_2)
from table_1 T1 join
     table_2 T2
     on T1.col_match = T2.col_match cross join
     (values ('value1', 'value12'), ('value2', 'value12'), ('value3', 'value3')
     ) v(t_col1, groupby)
     on v.t_col1 = t1.col_1
group by t1.groupby;
```

Or if you use a `case` expression and filtering:

```
select (case when t.col_1 = 'value3' then t.col_1 else 'value12' end) as grp,
       sum(col_2)
from table_1 T1 join
     table_2 T2
     on T1.col_match = T2.col_match
where t.col_1 in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
group by grp;
```